# Modeling Subclass (or Subtype) Constraints in an Entity-Relationship Diagram

Tags: database-design, erd, database-diagrams, subtypes

## Scenario description

Can someone help me out on how to model the situation that follows:

1. There is a *superclass* (or *supertype*) called `PRODUCTS`, which has the *subclasses* (or *subtypes*) named `FOOD` and `SHOES`.
2. There exists another *superclass* denominated `CUSTOMERS`, with the *subclasses* denominated `SHOE STORE` and `GROCERY STORE`.
3. I need to represent some rules that indicate that:

   - `FOOD` can only be delivered to `GROCERY STORES`.
   - `SHOES` can exclusively be distributed to `SHOE STORES`.

## Tentative diagrams

I have tried the two diagrams shown bellow:

[image: Diagrams]

## Diagrams considerations

**Top diagram**

I really do not like the duplication of (a) the same entity type, i.e., `ORDERS`, and (b) the relationships around it.

**Bottom diagram**

I am pretty sure this not the proper notation. Should I instead create the relationship on the *superclass* level and make a note that the restrictions will be implemented at the programming level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can make an `Orders` entity that is a relationship between `Products` and `Customers`. The `Orders` would have subclasses `FoodOrders` and `ShoeOrders`, which respectively would be the relationships between the subclasses of `Food - GroceryStores` and `Shoes - ShoeStores`.

```
                                            ┌───────────┐
                                            │ Employees │
                                            └─────┬─────┘
                                                  │
                                                  │
      ┌──────────┐               ┌────────┐       │       ┌───────────┐
      │ Products ├─── contain ───┤ Orders ├─── deliver ───┤ Customers │
      └────┬─────┘               └────┬───┘               └─────┬─────┘
           │                          │                         │
           │                          │                         │
          isA                        isA                       isA
          │ │                        │ │                       │ │
     ┌────┘ └────┐             ┌─────┘ └─────┐            ┌────┘ └────┐
     │           │             │             │            │           │
 ┌───┴──┐    ┌───┴───┐         │             │    ┌───────┴───────┐   │
 │ Food │    │ Shoes │         │             │    │ GroceryStores │   │
 └───┬──┘    └───┬───┘         │             │    └───────┬───────┘   │
     │           │       ┌─────┴──────┐      │            │     ┌─────┴──────┐
     └───────────│───────┤ FoodOrders ├──────│────────────┘     │ ShoeStores │
                 │       └────────────┘      │                  └─────┬──────┘
                 │                     ┌─────┴──────┐                 │
                 └─────────────────────┤ ShoeOrders ├─────────────────┘
                                       └────────────┘
```